# SimpleDB select count (*) Inconsistent iPhone

Tags: iphone, select, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

Anyone know why both AWS SimpleDB expressions work?

```
selectRequestClassVariable.selectRequestExpressionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count(*) from %@",DomainName];
```

In addition, this second expression works, but has '' around the domain. According to AWS, only the first should work.

```
selectRequestClassVariable.selectRequestExpressionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from `%@` where Attribute > '%ld' limit 2500",DomainName,number];
```

One is a select, the other is a select count(*). Anyone run into this inconsistency and know how to deal with it? Just to be clear, both expressions shown work. According to AWS only the first should.

I ask because I need a select count (*) that returns more than 2500. I've read that select only returns a max of 2500.

Thanks!

Comment: '%@' does not equal `%@` they haven't covered this in their documentation yet. AWS changed it from %@ to `%@`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct answer is `%@` not '%@'